# How to set up a cron job for insert query using php?

Tags: php, cron

Any one help me one this topic related to cron job?

How i setup cron job for php file.

Comment: I find the Wikipedia article pretty helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron, and Google provides more than enough tutorials: https://www.google.com/search?q=setup+cron. I also wouldn't consider cron a tool for programmers.

Comment: thanks Felix.. but i actully work on youtube script. i want to store all new youtube video links on my database. so i add cron job for insert.php file. any help regarding this ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what your script does, cron works the same for any script. Just have a look at the files above. All you have to do is provide the command to run the script.

Comment: I follow these command . now i have received blank mail from my server.. whats the problem here?

Comment: How should I know? I don't know what your script is doing.